# Highlight tag matches for better visibility

Tags: tags, cscope

When I search for occurrences of some frequent pattern (lets say finding a c symbol), I'll get a list of suggestions at the bottom of vim. Is there a way that the pattern is highlighted for easier lookup?

Here is how it actually looks like:
[image]

Here is a mockup of what I'd like it look like:
[image]

This would help the user see the slightly faster in the context.

Comment: Afaik this would require patching vim. But I would love to see it implemented!

Comment: worth pointing out these are cscope tags which are handled differently in vim's source code

Comment: @Mass really? I didnt realize there was a difference; ill have to reread the help on cscope

Comment: Gotta say those screen grabs are kind of a mess and not easy to read. Some people will probably be inclined to skip over your question (I nearly did) so you might consider cleaning them up. Try something less jarring than simulated giant black marker and reduce the window height a bunch as the point comes across after only a couple example lines.